# Pandas - pandas.DataFrame.from_csv vs pandas.read_csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas

What's the difference between:

`pandas.DataFrame.from_csv`, doc link: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_csv.html

and

`pandas.read_csv`, doc link: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html

Comment: I believe one of the most important differences is the default for index column. Using `from_csv` will default to use the first column as an index. `read_csv` defaults to `None` so an index will be created. `read_csv` should be best suited for most datasets.

Comment: Didn't even know `from_csv` existed, personally having looked at both I would use `read_csv` as it has far more options that should assist with data mangling

Comment: I think `pandas.DataFrame.from_csv` has now been removed. I'm unable to call it and your link gives a 404: Not Found error.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There is no real difference (both are based on the same underlying function), but as noted in the comments, they have some *different default values* (`index_col` is 0 or None, `parse_dates` is True or False for `read_csv` and `DataFrame.from_csv` respectively) and *`read_csv` supports more arguments* (in `from_csv` they are just not passed through).

Apart from that, it is **recommended to use `pd.read_csv`**.
`DataFrame.from_csv` exists merely for historical reasons and to keep backwards compatibility (plans are to deprecate it, see [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4916)), but all new features are only added to `read_csv` (as you can see in the much longer list of keyword arguments). Actually, this should be made more clear in the docs.

Comment: thanks joris. I would be interested in getting involved with the pandas project, unless you can think of a better library out there for data analysis or machine learning...

Comment: @joris: `index_col` defaults are the opposite -- 'None or 0' (I edited)

Answer (score 3):

Another difference is that `pandas.read_csv` is 46x to 490x as fast as `pandas.DataFrame.from_csv` (in my testing).

I tested it on Python 3.4.4 and pandas 0.19.2 on Windows on my proprietary csv file.