# Read in csv file faster

Tags: python, csv

I am currently reading in a large csv file (around 100 million lines), using command along the lines of that described in https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html e.g. :

```
import csv
with open('eggs.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
     for row in spamreader:
          process_row(row)
```

This is proving rather slow, I suspect because each line is read in individually (requiring lots of read calls to the hard drive). Is there any way of reading the whole csv file in at once, and then iterating over it? Although the file itself is large in size (e.g. 5Gb), my machine has sufficient ram to hold that in memory.

Comment: That code is not reading the file one line at a time. The input is read in appropriately-sized buffers.

Comment: It is more likely that it is slow because of RAM usage. A 5GB file probably takes much more than 5GB of RAM after parsing.

Comment: Yes - it turned out that it quickly used 26gb of ram, before my machine crashed! Lesson learnt...

Answer (score 3):

```
import pandas as pd
df =pd.DataFrame.from_csv('filename.csv')
```

This will read it in as a pandas dataframe so you can do all sorts of fun things with it

Comment: Maybe rather `read_csv`? See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26495408/pandas-pandas-dataframe-from-csv-vs-pandas-read-csv).

Answer (score 1):

> my machine has sufficient ram to hold that in memory.

Well then, call `list` on the *iterator*:

```
spamreader = list(csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way to read the entire file at once:

```
with open('eggs.csv', 'rb', 5000000000) as ...:
    ...
```

Reference: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open

Answer (score 0):

If your csv file larger then your ram then you can use

- DASK (Dask is a parallel computing and data analytics library for Python. It supports dynamic task scheduling optimized for computation as well as big data collections. )

[Dask Dataframe](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html) from [Dask Official](https://dask.org/) ... [Dask Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dask_(software))

with dask dataframe you can do data analysis even if you have big dataset

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `chunksize` in `read_csv` to read it in pieces and process it:

```
# chunksize is defined here
df = pd.read_csv("path/test.csv", chunksize=10000)

for data in df: 
    print(data.shape)
```

[Source](https://techeasylearnt.blogspot.com/p/import-csv.html)

Comment: Please refrain from posting link only answers. Include the main point in the answer incase the link become invalid in the future

Comment: Got it. thanks for the info